# How to fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined during hashing password for GraphQL mutation with bcryptjs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I am relatively new to Node/GraphQL/MongoDB/Moogose.
I am trying to create a mutation to encrypt the user's password using bcryptjs instead of plain text. However, I am having this error:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined**

I came from Python background and I am having some difficulty understanding how async programming
Here's my code block of my schema.js

```
const RootMutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootMutationType',
    fields: {
    createUser: {
        type: UserType,
        args: {
            email: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
            password: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
        },
        resolve(parents, args) {
            User.findOne({ email: args.email })
                .then(user => {
                    if(user) {
                        throw new Error('This email has already been used!');
                    }
                    return bcrypt.hash(args.password, 12);    // Error at this line
                })
                .then(hashedPassword => {
                    let user = new User({
                        email: args.email,
                        password: hashedPassword,
                    });
                    return user.save();
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    throw err;
                });
        }
    }
```

I have tried, but i've gotten the error Cannot read property 'genSalt' of undefined:

```
createUser: {
            type: UserType,
            args: {
                email: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
                password: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
            },
            resolve(parents, args) {
                User.findOne({ email: args.email })
                    .then(user => {
                        if(user) {
                            throw new Error('This email has already been used!');
                        }
                        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
                            bcrypt.hash(args.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
                                let user = new User({
                                    email: args.email,
                                    password: hash,
                                });
                                return user.save();
                            });
                        });
                    });
```

**Update:**
I am now able to create a user in my MongoDB after change to the below:
Turns out it is because I am using:

`const {bcrypt} = require('bcryptjs');`

instead of

`const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');   // this is working`

Can someone explain what is the difference? I am using ES6.

Also my graphql **mutation** doesn't seem to return me the correct query. 
Mutation cmd

```
mutation {
  createUser(email: "test3@test.com", password: "testpassword") {
    email
    password
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createUser": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined` is fixed for me after
declare bcrypt like this:

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
```

instead of this

```
const {bcrypt} = require('bcryptjs');
```

Answer (score 27):

Try

```
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
```

Update:
The TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined error occurs when you are trying to access a property of an undefined variable. In this case, it seems that you were trying to access the hash property of an undefined variable when using bcryptjs.

The reason why switching to import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt' worked is because it imports the entire bcrypt module as an object, which includes the hash function. This means that when you call bcrypt.hash(), the hash function is being called from the imported module.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Why does this work?

Answer (score 0):

`const {bcrypt} = require('bcryptjs');` means grabbing a property called bcrypt inside of bcryptjs, which is not available.

you only do destructuring
`const { isEmail } = require("validator");`
when isEmail is one of the properties in validator.

Answer (score -2):

For ES6:

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
```

Comment: Actually, it should be `import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';`.